# using agile toolkit like other frameworks work?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

is there any way to use agile toolkit without using js features? I know that we can disable js lib (jUI) but I want to have normal CRUD and grids(without jquery)

In other word, can we use agile as if it was like other frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you won't be able to use some of the features of Agile Toolkit (including CRUD).

Commonly this is used in the Front-end development. For example, you would want to have your own Lister (or CompleteLister) template which will link directly to editing page:

[image]

Set `js_widget` property of Form to **null** to disable JS enhancement. This way Agile Form would be submitted normally, no AJAX. You would need to act accordingly inside `isSubmitted()` check.

CRUD, Popovers and many other features wouldn't work, but then again other frameworks don't offer them to you anyway.

See also:

- http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/lister